# Diffrence between Laravel Routing Method

Tags: php, laravel

what is the difference between both routing ? can anyone explain ?

1. Route::get('login', 'webcontroller@login');
2. Route::get('login', array('as' => 'login','uses'=>'webcontroller@login'));

Comment: Some one said to change the url in future but we also can update url there like
 Route::get('login', 'webcontroller@login'); => Route::get('newname', 'webcontroller@login');

Comment: @OP: Yeah you could. But it's not as easy if you referenced the Route URL in 600 different views ;) Get the idea?

Answer (score 0):

Well. There is the flexibility of Route object (i think it belongs to Symfony)

In the first statement, you explicitly say that you what controller's action a certain address should trigger (in your case it is 'login' which triggers `login()` of `WebController`).

In the second statement, you can add an "array" of settings for the controller's method, which, in your case you have specified a name. "`login`", which is the name of your `Route::get()` rule for the address `"/login"`, could be used any where in the system without you explicitly specifying any controller or url which gives you the ability to change whatever you like in the future, as long as you are consistent with your names.

You set a route:

```
Route::get("login", array('as'=>'login', 'uses'=>'LoginController@Login');
```

Then you can use it like:

```
$url = URL::route('profile');
```

Whil you are still able to change the url of your route:

```
Route::get("user/login", ...);
```

Without the need to change its uses of "name" within your project.

You can read about it on Laravel's official documentation:

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#named-routes

Answer (score 0):

In the number 2, you usea an alias , is easy for call de route in the code:

example:

```
<a href=" {{ route('user.list') }} ">
< span class="glyphicons glyphicons-link"></span>
  <span class="sidebar-title">Link</span>
</a>
```